# What causes SoundCloud track strings character limits?

Tags: android, soundcloud

[Simple Last.fm Scrobbler](https://github.com/tgwizard/sls) plans on having basic SoundCloud support in the newest version, but we have a problem with SoundCloud only releasing track strings of about 40 characters in length. Hence the information sent to last.fm or libre.fm is incomplete.

`com.android.music.metadatachanged` is the action being monitored.

The alternative [My Cloud Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycloudplayers.mycloudplayer) gives the full length track strings.

I was hoping to get feedback from SoundCloud Mobile developers about what is causing the track length shortages and if it will ever be fixed.